# How to upload multiple images to Deno?

Tags: mongodb, deno

I want to know, how can we upload multiple images using `Deno`, I'm using mongo Database.  I followed [Article](https://medium.com/recoding/uploading-file-or-image-in-deno-server-39992ca339f6) to Upload a single image to the server.

> app.ts

```
import { Application, Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';
import { viewEngine, engineFactory, adapterFactory } from 'https://deno.land/x/view_engine/mod.ts';
import { upload } from 'https://deno.land/x/upload_middleware_for_oak_framework/mod.ts';
// Setting up our view Engine
const ejsEngine = engineFactory.getEjsEngine();
const oakAdapter = adapterFactory.getOakAdapter();
// Initiate our Application and Router
const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();
app.use(viewEngine(oakAdapter, ejsEngine));
// Setting our router to handle request
router
    .get('/', (ctx) => {
        ctx.render('index.ejs')
    })
    .post('/upload', upload('uploads'), async (context: any, next: any) => {
        const file = context.uploadedFiles;
        console.log(file);
        context.response.redirect('/');
    });
// Passing Router as middleware
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());
// Server our app
console.log('App is listening on PORT 8000');
await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

> index.ejs

```
<body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/validated">
 <input type="file" name="fileName" multiple> <br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want to store the files on the server and links in the database?

Comment: yes, absolutely

Comment: That library is broken btw, you should not use it.

Comment: You should consider improving the formatting on your code. The code above is a lot harder to read than it could be.

Comment: Agree that the library is broken but can anyone suggest a suitable replacement for uploading files in deno/oak?